# Outlook and autodiscovery

Tags: outlook, autodiscovery, autodiscover

I am hosting an IMAP/SMTP server for my clients. (Dovecot / Postfix) In order for Thunderbird and Outlook mail clients to automatically discover the settings, I have set up autoconfig and autodiscover. However, with Outlook, it is not autodiscover.xml that is called but `autodiscover.json/v1.0/address@domain.com?Protocol=ActiveSync&RedirectCount=1.`

When I run the connection tests provided by Microsoft, it works. I can’t find any significant information on what this script should return.

ActiveSync seems to be dedicated to the Exchange service but I am using IMAP.

Do you have any information to give me? Can the call to  `autodiscover.json/v1.0/address@domain.com?Protocol=ActiveSync&RedirectCount=1`
somehow redirect to
`autodiscover.xml?`

Answer (score 0):

To configure Autodiscovery in IMAP, there are two major steps involved.

1.Adding an SRV Record in your DNS Manager or uploading an XML file.
2.Login using an email address in your domain.
You will not need to enter any of the server details while logging in.

The autodiscovery settings can easily be configured in Outlook using the IMAP protocol by manually adding an SRV record in your DNS manager or uploading an XML file.

The autodiscovery service also can be configured in Thunderbird using the IMAP protocol in two simple steps:

1.Uploading an XML file
2.Login using an email address from your domain.

About the detailed configuration steps ,you can info this website：[enter link description here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/autodiscovery-settings.html#:%7E:text=Autodiscovery%20for%20Outlook%3A%201%20Adding%20SRV%20Record%3A%20Login,the%20Microsoft%20Outlook%20application%20in%20your%20system.%20)

Comment: SRV Records is added. But Outllok call autodiscover.json/v1.0/address@domain.com?Protocol=ActiveSync&RedirectCount=1 instead of the XML file...

Comment: What is the protocol you are using? If you are using the server protocol ,it could cause Autodiscover issue. Please refer this Microsoft Blog:   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b?ocmsassetid=ha102823161&correlationid=778d1d8d-9ac2-449b-9624-1268559fa794&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us to check whether Autodiscover still exists.

Answer (score 0):

The request you are seeing is an autodiscover V2 request. You will find more information about it on [this page](https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2018/05/22/get-autodv2/). There is another page with very detailed information: [msxfaq](https://www.msxfaq.de/exchange/autodiscover/autodiscover_v2.htm) It is only in German though. So you would have to translate it with e.g. Google.

Regarding the question at the end: You can make redirects if you follow the points mentioned [here](https://www.msxfaq.de/exchange/autodiscover/autodiscover_redirect.htm). (Again only in German.)